# Howto use Bndtools and Egit Successfully

Tags: egit, bndtools

Eclipse Kepler, Bndtools 2.1.0.REL, EGit 3.03.

Create default Bndtools Component Development project.

Commit to a new repository outside the Eclipse workspace.

The proj files including cnf move to the repository, but....

The workspace in the repository view appears with a folder icon rather than the repo icon like the local repository etc.

What is the correct (or working way) to use bndtools with egit?

Follow Up.....

Turns out that committing to git works fine. My problem went away after restarting eclipse. Thanks to Ferry Huberts for pointing out that there is no problem using bndtools and git.

Comment: I don't see a question in here that can be answered. It is a bunch of sentence fragments. Please rewrite into the form of a problem you are having to which an answer can be provided.

Comment: @BJ on reading again, it is a bit terse.

Comment: @BJ See follow up above, seems I just needed reassurance that it works OK.